# Programa en C, exit y stdprn no han sido declarados

Tags: c

recién empecé a practicar con el libro Aprende C en 21 días. Uno de los primeros ejercicios se pide copiarlo tal y como está y correrlo, eso hice pero no corre (si, ya revisé que esté bien escrito). Dice que "exit" y "stdprn" no están declarados, qué puedo hacer? (Estoy usando DevC)

Código:

```
//Programa que imprime un listado de numeros en linea
#include<stdio.h>
void do_heading(char*filename);
int line, page;
main( int argv, char*argc[] ) 

{
char buffer[256];
FILE *fp;


if( argv < 2)
{
    fprintf(stderr," \n  Proper Usage is: ");
    fprintf(stderr," \n \n PRINT_IT filename.ext \n");
    exit(1);
}
if ( ( fp = fopen( argc[1], "r" )) == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr," Error al abrir el archivo, %s!",argc[1]);
    exit(1);
}

page = 0;
line = 1;
do_heading( argc[1] );

while( fgets( buffer, 256, fp ) !=NULL )
{
    if ( line % 55 == 0 )
        do_heading( argc[1] );
    
    fprintf( stdprn, "%4d:\t%s", line++, buffer);
}

fprintf( stdprn, "\f" );
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
void do_heading( char *filename)
{
  page++;

if( page>1 )
    fprintf( stdprn, "\f");
    
fprintf( stdprn, "Pagina: %d, %s \n \n", page, filename );      
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuerda que los archivos de cabecera te dan acceso a los métodos ahí definidos, en el caso de [exit](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exit) está definido en stdlib

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

En el caso de stdprn está definido únicamente para Windows, entonces debes de tener cuidado para qué S.O. estás trabajando, de igual manera te sugiero trabajar con funciones estándar si no estás enfocado hacia ningún S.O.

Y te dejo [este enlace](https://www.die.net/) donde puedes consultar las páginas del manual

Comment: Te sugiero siempre que tengas duda con el comportamiento de un lenguaje visitar las páginas con la documentación oficial, te pueden dar mucha información y de primera mano

Comment: Tenías razón, tuve que agregar ese archivo de encabezado para que reconociera esa función, de la biblioteca creo, con respecto a stdprn sigue diciendo que no está definida, estoy trabajando con Windows 10, así que busqué la función sola y en otro foro decía que se reemplazara stdprn por stdout y ya lo hice y ya corrió. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!